# .Net core 5 Swagger not working after publish in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, swagger-ui, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, swagger-2.0

I have build swagger UI in .net core 5.
It's working in local iis and kesterl but not working after publish to Kubernetes.
Below is my code sample:

Startup.cs
[image]

Website console
[image]

Comment: Please give more details for your Kubernetes set-up - how exactly K8s cluster is configured, what K8s version is used, is it bare-metal/on cloud?

Comment: @anarxz Hi, sorry for late reply 
Running on EKS version 1.21 in AWS.